# How to resolve "{errors:{message:'Id not specified in an update call', statusCode:'MISSING_ARGUMENT', }, id:null, success:'false', }" in list button

Tags: list-button

I am having a requirement like if lead industry(standard field) is equal to "education" , after clicking that button it should be changed to "Energy". But when i am doing that i am getting an error like above mentioned because the id i am getting is undefined which is null. Please help me out.. Below is my code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")} 
var userList = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Lead )};
var SelectedIds=''; 
for(var i=0;i < userList.length; i++)
{
SelectedIds+="'"+userList[i]+"',";
}
SelectedIds=SelectedIds.substring(0,SelectedIds.length - 1);
alert('id opbtained' + SelectedIds);
var updatedList = [];
if (userList[0] == null) 
{ 
     alert("Please select at least one record.");
} 
else
{ 
      var answer = confirm("Are you sure?");          
      if (answer==true) 
{   {
/*Formated Query*/
var strQuery="Select Industry,Id from Lead where ID  in ("+SelectedIds+")"; 
var result = sforce.connection.query(strQuery);
var records = result.getArray("records");
    alert('recrds' + records);
/*Formated Query  Ends */
           for (var n=0; n<records.length; n++) 
    { 
        if (records[n].get("Industry") == "Education")
        {
                    alert('inside loop');
                    var i = new sforce.SObject("Lead"); 
                    alert('reciddd'+records[n].id);                                             
                    i.id = records[n].id;
        i.Industry = "Energy";                      
        updatedList.push(i);
        }
              }               
             var upresult = sforce.connection.update(updatedList); 
if (upresult[0].getBoolean("success"))
{
             window.location.reload(); 
}
else
{
    alert("Error occurred in updating Lead :" + upresult[0]);

}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each of your SelectedIds are comprised of userList[i]. Your record change updates need to be applied to those records. And the updates to those records are also what need to be returned and applied with your code. From reading it, that doesn't appear to be what you're doing.

One thing you can do is update the results of the query and then return the records to your page. You don't need to create "new leads" to do that, just iterate on the fields in the returned results and perform the update. Your code gets obfuscated in the way you have it written.